# Reclassifying a polygon using ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, reclassify

I am trying to reclassify a polygon into three classes:

- 1 and 2 = 5
- 3 and 4 = 3
- 5 = 1

I have been trying to do this by calculating a new field in the attribute table but I am very inexperienced with Python so have tried it VB script. Is there anyone out there that could help me with a basic IF function?

I have tried this:

```
if [Sal_AlkCL]=1,2 Then
 [Salscore] = "5"
if [Sal_AlkCL]=3,4 Then
 [Salscore] = "3"
if [Sal_AlkCL]=1 Then
 [Salscore] = "1"
end if
```

Comment: Can you reformat your code to show how it's actually entered into the GIS. In fact you don't even mention which GIS system you are using...

Comment: Apologies I am using ArcMap version 10

Comment: What data type is the field Sal_AlkCL? Can one row hold a value like 1, 2? If so it's probably a text field. Or are you trying if [Sal_AlkCL] = 1 or [Sal_AlkCL] = 2 Then... where Sal_AlkCL is a numeric field?

Comment: Sal Alk is a numeric field. It only has values 0-5.

Comment: there are a few of variables, why dont you try to select by attributes 1 and 2 first, and with the field calculator, in a new column, change all of these by 5, after that select by attributes again now 3 and 4 and change it for 3. it sounds a lot of time but is quickly in the practice. I know is not the most brilliant answer but sometimes we need to keep it easy. sorry if im disturbing you :) (Im thinking in ArcGIS but I think it could work in qGIS, too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK the syntax is incorrect, the example code using fields from my dataset will help you set up the correct VB script structure.

```
if [NAID] = 23 or [NAID] = 38 then
 x = 5
elseif [NAID] = 34 or [NAID]= 35 then
 x = 3
else
 x = 1
end if
```

You run this field calculate on a field (in my example its a *numeric* field called q), and you put `x` into the bottom box as shown below:

[image: Field calculate]

Comment: I tried this but I still get an error 999999 expected If?

Comment: if [Sal_AlkCL]= 1 or [Sal_AlkCL] = 2 then
x= 5
elseif [Sal_AlkCL]= 3 or [Sal_AlkCL] = 4 then
x= 3
else
x= 1

Comment: Sorry this does work beautifully if you close with an endif! Apologies!!!!!

Comment: Ah the dreaded missing off of the End If, everyone falls foul to it eventually! :)